# I have Error in paypal phonegap plugin after enter buyer mailid

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have Error in paypal phonegap plugin after enter buyer mailid 
"The application is not approved to use the following parameter with this type of payment" what is the mean of this error

I think my error is here

```
var obj = {
           server : 'ENV_SANDBOX',
           appId : 'APP-80W284485P519543T'
       };
```

Answer (score 0):

The original developer of the PayPal plugin just recently posted this message to the repo.

> This Plugin is significantly out of date for both PhoneGap and PayPal.
>   It should only be used as a reference for an updated implementation.

So it looks like some more work needs to be done to update this plugin to todays PayPal API.

Comment: then i should wait for update version of PayPal plugin for phonegap ..or i may create my own appid using paypal